# Sort output of aws-cli ec2 describe-instances by Hostrecord (Route53::RecordSet)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

Currently i use the following command to get all instance id's from my stack in json format:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query Reservations[*].Instances[*].InstanceId[] --filters Name=tag-key,Values=aws:cloudformation:stack-name Name=tag-value,Values=Stack-Name-XYZ --output=json
```

This command works fine but returns the instance id's in a different order which I need to change. I need the instances in the output sorted by the Hostrecord (Route53::RecordSet) or by the Logical ID in ascending order. For example: I have three instances with Hostrecord `project1-avad.name.com, project2-avad.name.com, project3-avad.name.com`. I want to get the instance id from project1 first, etc.

Unfortunately the documentation of [describe-instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html) does not show a way to sort the output.

**My Question:**

Is it even possible to sort the output the way I want? If yes, where can I find the required documentation?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of doing this is by piping it through python, ruby or some other scripting language that can parse your JSON and output it as desired.

Alternately, if you're performing actions to multiple instances at once and this is not a once-off change, you should probably be looking into an orchestration framework like AWS  CloudFormation or [Hashicorp's excellent Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/) in order to manage this via a DSL rather than through hand-built scripting.